# Cannot fetch Camunda job variables in pyzeebe worker

Tags: python, camunda, zeebe

I have written a Python `pyzeebe` worker that is supposed to interact with my database using the values that the variables of the previous user task in the `Camunda BPMN` hold. I have defined a user task with a form. I have also created a service task and defined the `taskDefinition`.

It seems like the worker can indeed communicate with my `zeebe` but it is unable to fetch the variables of the form.

```py
from pyzeebe import ZeebeWorker, Job, create_insecure_channel
import asyncio
import psycopg2
import logging
async def handle_database_transaction(job: Job) -> dict:
    variables = job.variables

    # Log the received variables at INFO level
    logging.info(f"Received variables: {variables}")

    selected_date = variables.get('selected_date')
    selected_project_id = int(variables.get('selected_project_id')) if variables.get('selected_project_id') else None

    # Log the extracted field values
    logging.info(f"Selected date: {selected_date}, Project ID: {selected_project_id}")

    # if selected_date and selected_project_id is not None, I perform the insert query with my database.

    return {}
```

And here is the MappingIO in my BPMN:

```xml
<zeebe:ioMapping>
   <zeebe:output source="=select_0swn49" target="output_project" />
   <zeebe:output source="=datetime_gporzh" target="output_date" />
</zeebe:ioMapping>
<zeebe:ioMapping>
   <zeebe:input source="=output_project" target="selected_project_id" />
   <zeebe:input source="=output_date" target="selected_date" />
</zeebe:ioMapping>
```

What part of the procedure am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like people have had the same problem and the issue is with Pyzeebe source code. Do you have any idea where to look for the issue in the codebase?
Github similar issues:
https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/pyzeebe/issues/315
https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/pyzeebe/issues/311

Comment: See https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/pyzeebe/issues/315#issuecomment-1923155344